# Beginning/end of line for screen on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, gnu-screen

Using screen on Mac OS X, I want to know how to go to the beginning/end of the line.

Usually I use `^ + A` / `^ + E` on terminal , but that doesn't work for screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd> is screen's default escape sequence.  So, if you want to actually pass it through to something running inside screen you need to use <kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>.  <kbd>Ctrl+e</kbd> should work fine as that's nothing screen captures.